# ImproperlyConfigured exception when starting server. "The included URLconf 'percentsystem .urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I making a Django website, and everything was alright until the moment when i added new path in urls.py:

app's urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.members_list, name='members_list_url'),
    path('create/', views.MemberCreate.as_view(), name='member_create_url'),
    path('<str:nickname>/', views.MemberPage.as_view(), name='member_page_url')
]
```

and an error message occured:

```
(venv) D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\app\percentsystem>manage.py runserve
r
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\
resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inn
er
    self.run()
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils
\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\
checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\
resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils
\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\percents_system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\
resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'percentsystem.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

project's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

from .views import to_home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('system/', include('system.urls')),
    path('', to_home, name='home'),
]
```

I tried to change `path('system/', include('system.urls'))` to `re_path('system/', include('system.urls')),`
It didn't helped.
Also, if to comment the `path('system/', include('system.urls')),` string, like that

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

from .views import to_home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('system/', include('system.urls')),
    path('', to_home, name='home'),
]
```

then server starts normally.
I don't know what to do, i trying to fix this problem already 2 days.

Also, if it's needed, app's views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Member
from .utils import ObjectCreateMixin
from .forms import MemberForm

from django.core.paginator import Paginator

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'system/base_system.html')

def members_list(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search', '')

    if search_query:
        members = Member.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_query) | Q(surname__icontains=search_query))
        paginator = Paginator(members, 2)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        is_paginated = page.has_other_pages()
        is_searching = True

        href = "?search={}&page=".format(search_query, page_number)

        print(is_searching)

        if page.has_previous():
            prev_url = '?search={}&page={}'.format(search_query, page.previous_page_number())
        else:
            prev_url = '?search={}'.format(search_query)
        if page.has_next():
            next_url = '?search={}&page={}'.format(search_query, page.next_page_number())
        else:
            next_url='?search={}'.format(search_query)
    else:
        members = Member.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(members, 2)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        is_paginated = page.has_other_pages()
        is_searching = False

        href = "?search={}&page=".format(search_query, page_number)

        print(is_searching)

        if page.has_previous():
            prev_url = '?page={}'.format(page.previous_page_number())
        else:
            prev_url = ''
        if page.has_next():
            next_url = '?&page={}'.format(search_query, page.next_page_number())
        else:
            next_url=''

    context = {
        'page': page,
        'is_paginated': is_paginated,
        'prev_url': prev_url,
        'next_url': next_url,
        'search_query': search_query,
        'href': href,
        'members_amount': len(members)
    }

    return render(request, 'system/members_list.html', context=context)

class MemberCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    model_form = MemberForm
    template = 'system/member_create.html'
    model = Member

class MemberPage(View):
    def get(self, request, nickname):
        member = get_object_or_404(Member, nickname__iexact = nickname)
        return render(request, 'system/member_page.html', context={'member': member})
```

and app's models.py

```
from django.db import models
import os
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index = True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 32, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    stake = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField('Task', related_name='tasks')
    stake_chart = models.ManyToManyField('StakeUpdate', related_name='stake_updates')
    contact_info = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    about = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    card_mini = models.FilePathField()
    card_full = models.FilePathField()
    member_photo = models.FileField(upload_to = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'media'))
    member_photo_path = models.FilePathField(default=os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'media'), 'empty_user_photo.png'))
    stake_chart_photo = models.FilePathField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('member_page_url', kwargs={'nickname': self.nickname})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['reg_date']

class Task(models.Model):
    adresser = models.ManyToManyField('Member', related_name='member')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length = 512, db_index=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class StakeUpdate(models.Model):
    new_stake = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    change = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comments = models.TextField(db_index=True, null=True)
```

Comment: The exception is saying that "percentsystem.urls" does not contain any patterns but your code does not try to load this urls file. Have you excluded some code from the question?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't clearly understand you. Are you talking about ROOT_URLCONF = 'percentsystem.urls' ?

Comment: Problem is already solved. Thank everybody who tried to help.